# Drupal Form Ajax not updating form on first click

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

```
function _ajax_ticket_info($form,&$form_state)
{
    $subscriber = $form['info']['ticket']['subscribe'];
    _ticket_subscribe($subscriber['#value'],$subscriber['#name']);

    // Dunno if this is needed or not
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;


    return $form;
}
function _ticket_info($form,&$form_state,$node) {

    $is_subscribed = _ticket_is_subscribed($node->nid);
    $subscriber_count = count(_ticketsys_get_subscribers($node));

    $form = [
        '#prefix' => "<div id='ticket-info-form'>",
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];
    // other form fields here not that important 
    // just focusing on my problem 
    $form['info']['ticket']['subscribe'] = [
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => $is_subscribed,
    '#name' => $node->nid,
    '#id' => 'ticket-subscribe',
    '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '_ajax_ticket_info',
        'wrapper' => 'ticket-info-form',
        'effect' => 'fade',
    ],
];
return $form;
}
```

So the problem is i'm using that code to update my form without reloading the page and when i do that it only executes the replacement on the second time i clicked the button $form['info']['ticket']['subscribe'] and i notice using inspect element on chrome that the form id and other form fields have --2 on their ids and increasing every time i click the Subscribe button

Any ideas whats wrong here. I really need to fix this thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the button type to "submit", and specifying a custom submit handler:

```
$form['info']['ticket']['subscribe'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#submit' => [['ticket_submit_handler']]
    '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => 'ticket_ajax_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'ticket-info-form',
    ],

    // ...
];
```

In the submit handler:

- Change any variables in form_state storage that need to persist.
- Tell the form to rebuild itself (instead of doing a redirect after submission), in order to keep the form state.
- Do other stuff.

e.g.

```
function ticket_submit_handler(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['storage'][] = ;
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    // ...
}
```

In the AJAX callback:

- Return the part of the form that will replace the 'wrapper'. In your case, it seems to be the entire form.
- Don't do anything else here.

e.g.

```
function ticket_ajax_callback(&$form, &$form_state) {
    return $form;
}
```

AFAIK, when the user clicks your AJAX button, the following functions will run, in order:

1. Form validation (if any).
2. `ticket_submit_handler`
3. Form builder, to rebuild the entire form, even if we only need a part.
4. `ticket_ajax_callback`, which returns a part of the form, which is sent to the browser.

For more information, see the [example code](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc/function/ajax_example_add_more/7.x-1.x) in the Drupal 7 documentation.